# How to subdivide an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to split an array into segments by percents. For example, divide 100 elements into segments occupying `[1/3,1/4,5/12]`, but `[1/3,1/4,5/12]*100=[33.3,25,41.7]`, so it's necessary to adjust them to integers `[33,25,42]` (others like `[34,24,42]` or `[33,26,41]` are also acceptable, a wandering within 1 is not important).

Currently I use a loop to do this recursively

```
function x = segment(n,pct)
x = n * pct;
y = fix(x);
r = x - y;
for ii = 1 : length(r)-1
    [r(ii),r(ii+1)] = deal(fix(r(ii)),r(ii+1)+r(ii)-fix(r(ii)));    
end
x = y + r;
```

`segment(100,[1/3,1/4,5/12])` gives `[33,25,42]`.

Is there better way without recursive loop?

Comment: Is `round(n*pct)` what you looking for..?

Comment: @Adiel No, `sum(round(n*pct))` is not guaranteed to be `n`

Comment: Oh, I get. So I would just compute this number, and if I get `100-n` I would increment the `n` elements that closer to their round. The same for `100+n` with decrements... Would that fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use Adiel's comment for most of the cases, and just catch any rogue result after and correct it, only if it needs to be corrected:

```
function out = segmt( n , pct )

% This works by itself in many cases 
out = round(n.*pct) ;

% for the other cases:
% if the total is not equal to the initial number of point, the
% difference will be affected to the largest value (to minimize the
% percentage imbalance).
delta = sum(out) - n ;
if delta ~= 0
    [~,idx] = max( out ) ; 
    out(idx) = out(idx) - delta ;
end
```

Comment: just an additional comment: There is no input checking here. This example assume that the sum of percentages given in input makes up to 100%. You should probably add a check conditions for that at the start of the function and return an error or warning if the input is wrong.

Comment: A quicker implement, except the comment  `minimize the percentage imbalance` is not alway true. It could be more imbalanced.